# Принцип работы RemoveAll с полями класса

Tags: c#

Есть лист `private List<Fish> _fishes;` Из этого листа я хочу удалить все объекты, у которых `Age = _lifeTime`. Не пойму как мне все элементы перебрать, обязательно ли тут цикл `for` делать? `_fishes.RemoveAll(i => _fishes[0].Age == _fishes[0].GetLifeTime());`
Конечно есть и другие способы, но мне интересен именно RemoveAll.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Aquarium aquarium = new Aquarium();
            aquarium.CheckLifeTime();
        }
    }

class Aquarium
    {
        private List<Fish> _fishes;

        public Aquarium()
        {
            _fishes = new List<Fish>()
            {
                new Fish(1),
                new Fish(2),
                new Fish(2),
                new Fish(2),
                new Fish(2),
            };
        }

        public void CheckLifeTime()
        {
            _fishes.RemoveAll(i => _fishes[0].Age == _fishes[0].GetLifeTime());
        }
    }

class Fish
    {
        public int Age { get; private set; }
        private int _lifeTime = 2;
        
        public int GetLifeTime()
        {
            return _lifeTime;
        } 

        public Fish(int age)
        {
            Age = age;
            LifeTime = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ```_fishes.RemoveAll(i => i.Age == i.GetLifeTime());```

Comment: Гуглил как же работает RemoveAll, так и не получилось разобраться. Теперь я понял как это работает, также и как и foreach, спасибо Владимир!
Можете добавить как ответ, я помечу галочкой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вот так должно быть понятно:

```
_fishes.RemoveAll(i => i.Age == i.GetLifeTime());
```

i - здесь каждый элемент